# After enabling Commerce Cart Ajax module +/- feature of Commerce Extra module doesn't work

Tags: commerce, ajax

First of all, I installed Commerce Extra module and enabled "QUANTITY" feature, and everything worked like charm. Then I installed Commerce Cart Ajax module and did needed things to make this ajax module works on /cart page. It seems like everything works, but when I tried to press on "+" or "-" buttons - the value of text field with quantity didn't change. Also I noticed that when I clicked on these buttons the error("Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function") appeared in Chrome's console.

I use Drupal Commerce 7.x-1.9, Commerce Cart Ajax 7.x-1.0, Commerce Extra 7.x-1.0-alpha1

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The error you get is not necessarily a bug. It is more likely related to a jQuery version issue. Try installing jQuery update, and set the version to 1.8+ and the version for the admin pages to 1.5 and see if that works. If you still have issues then other options can be explored (there are other modules that can update blocks and views via ajax)

Comment: I've tried to set others versions of jQuery, but it still have the error. I had installed Ajax Login-Register module, and may be these two modules affect to each other?

Comment: I've tried to disable Ajax Login-Register module, and it still have the error. So, the problem is not connected with this module. Have you any other ideas?

Comment: There are two commerce ajax cart modules (dc_cart_ajax and commerce_ajax_cart). Try the other one. And lastly try authcache block. [Tutorial: Commerce Kickstart 2 and Authcache 2](https://www.drupal.org/node/2037015). The tutorial does not install authcache block so look for my comment at the bottom of that page.

Comment: I've tried to use both of these modules, and nothing changed. I didn't try Authcache 2, I didn't get how can this help to solve my problem. Now, I'm trying to imitate the Commerce Cart Ajax's actions, but without enabled Commerce Cart Ajax module. And now I need to trigger click on button "Update cart". But this doesn't work: `$(".commerce-line-item-views-form .form-actions.commerce-line-item-actions.form-wrapper input.form-submit.ajax-processed").trigger('click');` I think it's very strange..